# Are BSTR UTF-16 Encoded?

Tags: windows, unicode, bstr

I'm in the process of trying to learn Unicode?  For me the most difficult part is the Encoding.  Can BSTRs (Basic String) content code points U+10000 or higher?  If no, then what's the encoding for BSTRs?

Comment: I am sure this will be very helpful if you are trying to understand character set, encoding etc etc. [encoding and char set](http://phillyjug.jsync.com/file_download/51)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Microsoft-speak, Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374081%28VS.85%29.aspx) is generally synonymous with UTF-16 (little endian if memory serves). In the case of [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx), the answer seems to be *it depends*:

> - On Microsoft Windows, consists of a string of Unicode characters (wide or
>     double-byte characters).
> - On Apple Power Macintosh, consists of a single-byte string.
> - May contain multiple embedded null characters.

So, on Windows, yes, it can contain characters outside the basic multilingual plane but these will require two 'wide' chars to store.

Comment: I disassembled the system functions SysStringByteLen and SysStringLen.  Both return the byte length prefix but SysStringByteLen first divides it by 2.  Doesn't this mean the system is using UCS-2 encoding?

Comment: @Mike: I think that the documentation for `SysStringLen` is wrong, it returns the number of 16-bit **code units** in the string. Characters with code point U+10000 and higher use two 16-bit code units in UTF-16.

Comment: @dalle: That makes a lot of sense. Do you know of a function that returns the number of bytes?

Comment: @Mike - APIs generally don't try to get clever when it comes to length and variable-width encodings. The number of chars does not necessarily equal the number of Unicode code points. (You'll see the same behaviour in C# and Java.) IMHO, UTF-16 over UCS-2 support becomes more relevant in areas like font rendering and transcoding. Counting the code points would not necessarily be all that useful - a sequence of code points can combine together to render a single grapheme. http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/ It is more useful to know how much storage the artefact requires.

Comment: @McDowell: At this point in time, the only thing I care about is how many bytes are used to represent the string.  I don't need to interpret the code points.  I actually don't need to know the encoding just the start address of the string and its length in bytes.

Comment: @McDowell and @dalle: Sorry I missed one of your points.  BSTR uses two bytes per code point.  A character can use more then one code point.  Thank you both... that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

BSTR's on Windows originally contained UCS-2, but can in principle contain the entire unicode set, using [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates). UTF-16 support is actually up to the API that receives the string - the BSTR has no say how it gets treated. Most API's support UTF-16 by now. ([Michael Kaplan](http://www.siao2.com/2005/05/11/416552.aspx) sorts out the details.)

The windows headers still contain another definition for BSTR, it's basically

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(OLE2ANSI)
   typedef wchar_t OLECHAR;
#else
   typedef char OLECHAR;
#endif
typedef OLECHAR * BSTR;
```

There's no real reason to consider the `char`, however, unless you desperately want to be compatible with whatever this was for. (IIRC it was active - or could be activated - for early MFC builds, and might even have been used in Office for Mac or something like that.)

Comment: BSTRs on Windows use UTF-16, not UCS-2.

Comment: *originally* contained - but I've updated to avoid misunderstandings. In a sense, a BSTR by itself is neither UCS-2 nor UTF-16, it's just an array of `wchar_t`'s, and e.g. `SysStringLen` counts surrogate pairs as two characters.

Comment: You used to be able to switch the OLECHAR (and thus function signatures that used it between narrow (CP_ACP) and wide (UTF-16) by `#definine OLE2ANSI`, similar to how you can switch other Win32 functions by defining `UNICODE` or MSVCRT by defining `_UNICODE`. This was [removed starting in ATL 7.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx), and now it's always wide.